# Software Updater misbehaving since upgrade to 22.04

Tags: updates, update-manager

I've been a long time Ubuntu LTS user. My system has been upgraded several times, most recently to 22.04. To be honest, I don't even recall which LTS release was the first I used. It probably goes back to 2016 or 2014 though. Somewhere back there.

With 22.04 I have encountered problems. Most were related to the SNAP package of Firefox, which I removed and swapped out for the regular distribution. That seems to have corrected those errors.  (Details [here](https://jrpstonecarver.medium.com/is-it-time-to-abandon-ubuntu-e927f602b975), instructions for what I did [here](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/), just in case it matters.)

However, this question is about the Software Updater. Ever since the 22.04 upgrade it sometimes shows me software that is available to Upgrade, but it won't let me select any of it. Here is a recent example:

[image: software updater before update is applied]

I had to dig to find out what the boxes with exclamation marks mean - upgrade available, vs. update available - but I cannot select them. They are grayed out.

Which packages it lists varies with a given run.

I could go run apt to deal with these, but I don't know if it is safe to do so. Perhaps they need some other piece of software to be updated (or upgraded) before I upgrade them? And if it is safe to upgrade them, why not just have the software updater do it automatically?

I stress, this has never happened before in any of my previous LTS installations, and I have no clue why the behavior changed. I know it did change after the 22.04 upgrade. I also know that I have done nothing to avoid updates with the exception of avoiding the Firefox SNAP since that was utterly unreliable.

A second question that might be related. The update pictured above installed a new kernel. Fair enough, but the updater has stopped telling me that a reboot is needed after a kernel installation. The above update finished and gave me this:

[image: image of software updater after update is complete]

No indication a reboot is required, all the same packages that it told me need upgrades are still listed, and in addition it now includes the old kernel packages to remove.

But I haven't even rebooted. In 20.04 when I installed a new kernel it came back with an empty package list and told me a reboot was required. Only on subsequent runs of the software updater would it list the kernel packages that could be removed.

This behavior change hit with 22.04 as well.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?  Between these issues, the Firefox SNAP (which was unstable in the extreme), and some GNOME weirdness I am thinking it might be time to find a new distro. Alternately, maybe enough cruft has built up over the years that I need to do a complete fresh install. Perhaps that would address things like this? That would be painful, but it could be done.

Thanks in advance for any help possible. Or even just confirmation that someone else is seeing these weird things with the software updater.

EDIT 9/22/22

user535733 mentions that Libre Office uses phased updates and suggested this command to see the policy:

```
apt-cache policy libreoffice
```

When I run that, I get this:

```
libreoffice:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
     1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

No mention of phased updates. But it says that package is not installed, so I tried one of the packages listed in the image above that was in the list anc could not be selected:

```
$ apt-cache policy libreoffice-help-common
libreoffice-help-common:
  Installed: 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:7.3.6-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:7.3.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

Still no indication of phased releases there. Am I missing something?

I also note that it isn't only LibreOffice that has done this. I have seen quite a few other packages show up this way, but only since 22.04 arrived.

This morning's run of the software updater had a large number of packages in it, none of which was a new kernel. But this time it did tell me a reboot was required. And of course it doesn't tell me which package caused the reboot to be needed.

I need to go digging for any sort of log the software updater might leave behind. Maybe there is something in there to explain all this weirdness?

Edit 9/25

I've mentioned that packages other than LibreOffice wind up in this same state: listed as available for upgrade but unselectable in the software updater UI.  Here is a screen capture showing some others that were in that state on Sept 8. I didn't originally include this image because I thought the ones above would be adequate. But since LibreOffice can do phased updates, perhaps that hid the depth of the issue. So...

[image: software updater showing other packages that I cannot select]

I'm still looking to understand this, or to report it if it really is one or more bugs. The outstanding questions as I see them are:

- Why does software updater show me packages I cannot select only after the 22.04 upgrade?
- Is it a bug or is it deliberate? (Note that the UX in this case is terrible... you can't select them and there is no explanation for it, so why even show them?)
- Why does software updater no longer inform me that a reboot is needed after a kernel update?  Again bug or feature?  (I suppose some kernel updates are not security related and can therefore just wait for the next "natural" reboot, but in that case software updater should not immediately come back and tell me I can remove old kernel packages.)

Thanks again for any and all insight into this.

Comment: I don't see anything weird. #1: Looks like you have introduced package conflicts. If you resolve those conflicts, the problem will go away. If you don't resolve them, then eventually they may (or may not) break your system. #2: Looks like the system is not asking to install anything. It is asking to remove older --and unused-- kernel packages.

Comment: The unused kernel packages were expected. A new kernel had just been installed by the previous update, so it wants to remove an older one. The issue is the other packages which can be upgraded but cannot be selected.

UPDATE: this morning the software updater did install all of the packages for libreoffice. They were automatically selected (unlike the morning before) and installed just fine.  This is the new behavior in the software updater: It now shows packages that could be installed but won't let you select them. No clue why. Thankfully it (apparently) does later install them.

Comment: Also note the second issue: no longer stating when a reboot is required (like after a kernel update). That seems to be a bug.

Comment: The Libreoffice package issue is Phased Updates -- see `apt-cache policy libreoffice`, and look for the `(phasing xx%)`. Update Manager has used Phased Updates for almost a decade, though it is understandably confusing the first time you encounter it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, user535733. No luck though. I've edited the description with what I saw when I tried the command you suggested. No hint at all about phased updates.

Comment: That means since yesterday phasing completed. The `(phasing xx%)` only shows while phasing is in progress, and only lasts a few days.

Comment: OK. I'll buy that. But I still don't have a clue about the other (non-libreoffice) packages that have shown up this way, or why I have seen *nothing* like this has before in years. Not to mention the fact that the software showing me packages I cannot select for installation is really poor UX. Nor the fact that kernel updates no longer seem to notify me that a reboot is required. It feels like something has changed here.

Comment: Edited above at the bottom: Added another image showing additional packages that have been in this weird state recently, and clarified the questions I have.

Comment: @Pilot6, Mostly, it does. I have mostly given up on this, to be honest. The software updater just randomly shows me packages that need to be updated but cannot be selected now. A day or three later they show up again and can be selected. If this is phased updates, I guess that's fine, though I have never seen this before, going way back in Ubuntu versions. Why it started showing up with 22.04 I don't understand. But so far these things all eventually resolve given time.

Comment: @Pilot6 The other part of the issue remains, though. When a new kernel is installed, all LTS versions of Ubuntu that I recall would tell me to reboot after running that installation. In 22.04 it doesn't tell me that anymore. Maybe there are kernels that require a reboot to fix security issues and those that just add features and so the reboot can wait, but it seems odd that the behavior changed. Or at least it apparently changed. As with the issue around phased updates, things change without notice, so I am in the dark.

Comment: @JeffPowell It is by design to "randomly" show this.